# Reference sender in UITapGestureRecognizer action

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer, sender

To set the stage, I have a 4x5 grid of UIImageViews that I would like to flip and show a new image upon tap. I'd like to accomplish this with a single @IBaction. I'm simply having a bit of trouble referencing the selected UIIMageView when a tap is recognized. I'm sure it's something very simple. I'm just now starting to work with UITapGestureRecognizer, so I don't know all the ins and outs just yet. Here's the @IBAction I'm trying to use:

```
@IBAction func tileTapped(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer, _ sender: UIImageView) {
    print("Tile Tapped: \(sender.tag)")
}
```

My print statement is giving me the following no matter what UIImageView is tapped:

> Tile Tapped: 0

My tags are set up to reference the row and column they fall in. For example, the tags for my first row are:

> 00, 01, 02, 03

My biggest challenge is simply retrieving the tag for the appropriate UIIMageView. Once I figure that out, I should be solid.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not a valid function for a gesture recognizer. See the documentation for `UIGestureRecognizer` on the possible signatures.

To access the view associated with the gesture, access the gesture's `view` property.

```
@IBAction func tileTapped(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if let view = recognizer.view as? UIImageView {
        print("Tile Tapped: \(view.tag)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is perfect. I'll mark as correct shortly.